# What is difference between self.get_serializer and Serializer object in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently I have started learning django rest framework and I came accross below kind of code for getting serializer object.

```
1)serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
2)serializer = MyDataTypeSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

By using above two method I am able to get almost same kind of output so I have tried to find difference between those but not able to find any.

I have used above method likewise in my viewset.

```
class MyDataTypeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyDataTypeSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = MyDataType.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id).order_by('-created_at')

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            serializer = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
            return return_success(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        #serializer = MyDataTypeSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return return_success(serializer.data)
```

Please if anyone knows let me know difference between these two methods and how to decide which method to use in which condition.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you bother to look at the code for get_serializer()?  https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L103 .  It just gets the class, and then passes your arguments through.  Its 3 lines.

Comment: But I want to know differences between these two methods. When should I use which one?

Comment: You've not shown where you want to use them.  One is a base method of the view, and used by default by the framework.  The other can be used manually if/where needed.  You normally don't need to call **either** of them directly in a viewset.  The first one just constructs the context object and calls your #2 line.

Comment: I have edited question how I have used it in my project.

Answer (score 5):

`get_serializer()` also takes care of passing in the viewset's serializer context, and calls `get_serializer_class()` to figure out which serializer class to use.

Unless that function has been customized from [the viewset default as linked by Andrew in the comments](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/acbd9d8222e763c7f9c7dc2de23c430c702e06d4/rest_framework/generics.py#L103-L110), and `serializer_class = MyDataTypeSerializer` has been set,

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
serializer = MyDataTypeSerializer(
  queryset,
  many=True,
  context=self.get_serializer_context(),
)
```

Comment: So I think,  in above situation using self.get_serializer is more preferable than using MyDataTypeSerializer instance. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd use.